# RN Firebase - okhttp3 version mismatch on Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Attempting to integrate RN with Firebase. Apparently I'm getting the next error:

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
   Dependency path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.3.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
   Dependency path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
   Dependency path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
   Constraint path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.11.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.11.0
   Constraint path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.11.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.11.0
   Constraint path 'getnow:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' strictly '3.11.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.11.0
```

Does anyone has an idea how to deal with this? : (

Gradle version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Firebase version from package.json:

```
"react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1"
```

From build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
```

Comment: Hi @alex.mironov did you find any solution?
I am getting same issue.

Comment: hi @alex i i too facing same issue. can you plz share the solution?

Answer (score 1):

just change in android/build.gradle 
from com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 seemed to fix it...